# How to add direct routes(proto kernel scope link) to non-main table automatically

Tags: networking, kernel, router

When I add an IP to interface,the kernel will add a direct route to main table,and if I delete the IP,the kernel will delete the direct route from main table.As follows:

```
root@template:~# ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev eth2 
root@template:~# ip route show table main | grep 192.168.10
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 
root@template:~# ip addr del 192.168.10.1/24 dev eth2
root@template:~# ip route show table main | grep 192.168.10     
root@template:~#
```

If add another route table to /etc/iproute2/rt_tables,how to make the new table works like main table add/del direct route automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you can't - this behavior appears to be hardcoded into the kernel.

When a new route is added, `fib_add_addr` in `net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c` is called ([see here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c#L1097)). Provided the `IFA_F_NOPREFIXROUTE` flag is not set on the request (which would come from the `noprefixroute` argument to the `ip` command in userspace), while adding the address the kernel will automatically create a route for the address prefix via a call to `fib_magic(RTM_NEWROUTE, ...)` ([see here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c#L1126)).

`fib_magic` decides what table to add the route to like so ([source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c#L1078)):

```
tb_id = (type == RTN_UNICAST) ? RT_TABLE_MAIN : RT_TABLE_LOCAL;
```

Since the link prefix route is a unicast route, it gets added to the main table.

You *can* however stop the kernel from adding this route to begin with by passing `noprefixroute` to the call to `ip addr add`, however. And then add it yourself to the right table by issuing something like `ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 scope link table 1000`